C# Winforms Constructor being called when settting visible to true
Overall problem is a screen performance issue. Here is what I "think" I have found out. It appears the constructor gets ran again when setting visible to true? I am not 100% sure about that as I am new to performance profiling. When I am looking at a form that I pre-load that is not visible then when the form is supposed to be shown I set the visible property to true I see entries calling the Constructor again which I am really confused at why that would be happening. Based on what I have read is that OnLoad should be called which I don't have anything in there but I do have a custom control that I made to be used for every button on the screen as this is a touch screen type situation. I waited a while before I tried to call on the screen I am trying to debug and then captured the performance metric in that time frame. What you would see is the custom buttons being loaded from the bottom right of the screen up to the top left and takes less than 1.5 seconds but still it's slow enough it makes me question what Is actually happening.
That's why I started doing a performance profile using visual studio 2022. The custom control is literally the following.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Layout;

namespace Wagon_Wheel_Net_Project
{
    internal class Custom_all_btn : Button
    {
        private bool ShouldDraw = false;
        private LinearGradientBrush myBrush = null;
        private int pluNO = 0;
        private decimal price;
        public All_Items.Item item { get; set; }
        public bool selected { get; set; }
        private bool dialogObject { get; set; }
        PictureBox selectedpic = new PictureBox();
        PictureBox checkedbox = new PictureBox();
        public List<All_Items.Item> Items { get; set; }
        public All_Items.sandwich sandwich { get; set; }
        public All_Items.specialty_sandwich specialty { get; set; }
        public All_Items.specialty_wrap specialtywrap { get; set; }
        public All_Items.soup soup { get; set; }
        public All_Items.Hot_Dog Hot_Dog { get; set; }

        public Custom_all_btn()
        {
        }

        public Custom_all_btn(string txt)
        {
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            Text = txt;
            selected = false;
            Items = new List<All_Items.Item>();
            //this.Font = new Font("Segoe UI",14,FontStyle.Bold);
        }

        public Custom_all_btn(string txt, Image img, int plu, decimal price)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
            ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            pluNO = plu;
            Image = img;
            Text = txt;
            selected = false;
            Items = new List<All_Items.Item>();


        }

        
    }
}


Its just text at the top and a picture box at the bottom. I format the text using a font. There is approximately 12-17 of the buttons on each Winform. So I am unsure how to diagnose any further. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Tried performance profiling and did not expect to see the constructor being called on a already pre-loaded form.

Settings the Visible Property to true causes a call to the CreateControl() method, for the affected Control and its child Controls

DoubleBuffered = true; and all other meaningful properties and states must be set in the default Constructor. Overloaded Constructors must call the default Constructor (e.g., public Custom_all_btn(string txt)) : this()

So pre-loading is not helping me is what you are saying?

WinForms is a thin wrapper around Win32's User32 and other APIs. It abstracts away many of the complications that exist when using those APIs, in particular, it allows you to use a property based API on a system that runs by listening to messages of the right format. So, even though your WinForms Form class has a constructor, you window is not Created until it becomes visible. Similarly, if you change a property that changes a window style that must be set at window creation time, your window will be Destroyed and then re- Created. What kind of performance issues are you seeing?

@Flydog57 Can I post a video anywhere that you could be able to see what I am seeing?
